# access textarea with spring-thymeleaf

Tags: java, javascript, spring

following Problem: I try to change the text of a textarea.
I'm using Sping and Thymeleaf.
Right now my Code looks like this:

Spring:

```
    [...]
    modelMap.addAttribute("Email", "035and so on");
    modelMap.addAttribute("Notes", "Please take this text and use it!");
    [...]
```

Thymeleaf:

```
    [...]
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <input name="Tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefonnummer"
        th:value="${Tel}" style="width: 100%;" />
    </div>
    <div><textarea class="form-control" rows="12"
        style="margin-top: 10px;"  placeholder="Sonstige Bemerkungen"
        name="notes" th:field="*{Notes}">
    </textarea></div>
    [...]
```

the telephone String works fine, but i dont know how to access the
Textarea. Would be glad if someone could help me.

Comment: `th:field`  and `th:value`  are different things. The field is for accessing a property of a model object which you don't use. You shold create a model object which contains all the properties you want, then use `th:field` for all those (instead of `th:value`). Spring will do the data binding when you submit the form and yuo can readily use the object in your controller. Saves you accessing all those rquest parameters yourself.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem finding that textarea does not support a value attribute.
If you are trying to insert thymeleaf variable into a html textarea, you can use text inlining.  So something like this...

```
<div><textarea class="form-control" rows="12"
    style="margin-top: 10px;"  placeholder="Sonstige Bemerkungen"
    name="notes" th:inline="text">[[${Notes}]]
</textarea></div>
```

Good reference here: http://loongest.com/uncategorized/thymeleaf/

Answer (score 13):

you can just use `th:text` it will work too. Bu I prefer @Amy's way.

Comment: Using `<textarea name="name" th:text="${whatever}"></textarea>`is surely the better way!

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same problem, you can try th:text, it works for me.

```
th:text="${Notes}"
```